# how to call using rawchip widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically, I have define a list of array but how to call the list on the label. can someone help me
[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            color: AppColor.white,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: RawChip(
              showCheckmark: false, 
              label: Text(widget.list, 
              style: TextStyle(
                color: isSelected ? Colors.black : const Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 110, 162), 
                fontFamily: 'Poppins' 
              ),),
              backgroundColor: isSelected ? Colors.white : const Color.fromARGB(255, 200, 222, 255),
              shape: const StadiumBorder(
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
      //selectedColor: Colors.red,
      selected: isSelected,
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          isSelected = isSelected ? false : true;
        });
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

`widget.variableName` is used to refer top level widget(`StatefulWidget` ). To get data within state class, just use local

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int widgetData;
  const MyWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.widgetData,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final int stateData = 3;

    late int makingLocal;
    
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      makingLocal = widget.widgetData;
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

in your case it will be just list  but.

```dart
  Container(
          child: Column(children: list),
        ),
```